# How to disable the 'pressed down' effect on the html buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

let playerTurn = 'X';

function runGame() {
 //for(i=0; i<9; i++) {
  buttons[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
   buttons[0].innerHTML = playerTurn;
  })
 }
```

```css
body {
 background-color: coral;
}

h1 {
 font-family: 'Lobster';
 font-size: 1.9rem;
 text-align: center;
}

button {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: relative;
 left: 35px;
 top: 35px;
 background-color: coral;
 border: none;
 margin: 4px;
 transition-duration: 500ms;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
 background-color: black;
}

.game-box {
 background-color: black;
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 border-radius: 10%;
 margin: auto;

}

.shave-left-top {
 border-top-left-radius: 10%;
}

.shave-right-top {
 border-top-right-radius: 10%;
}

.shave-left-bottom {
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10%;
}

.shave-right-bottom {
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>javaScript Tic Tac Toe</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>javascript Tic Tac Toe</h1>

 <div class="game-box">
  <div class="row-1">
   <input type="button" name=""> class="shave-left-top" onclick="runGame();"></button> 
   <button onclick="runGame();"></button> 
   <button class="shave-right-top" onclick="runGame();"></button> 
  </div>

  <div class="row-2">
   <button onclick="runGame();"></button> 
   <button onclick="runGame();"></button> 
   <button onclick="runGame();"></button> 
  </div>

  <div class="row-3">
   <button class="shave-left-bottom" onclick="runGame();"></button> 
   <button onclick="runGame();"></button> 
   <button class="shave-right-bottom" onclick="runGame();"></button> 
  </div>

 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to make a simple javascript tic tac toe game. Currently I'm trying to click a button and have its value changed and displayed, which isn't working the way i want it to. If you wanna take a look at why that is feel free, but the main question has to do with the button. When it's clicked it moves like 40px down, how do you disable that without using the disable attribute.

Comment: Can't see any "moving" buttons when running the snippet ..?

Comment: Have you considered **not** using a `button`? Maybe putting a listener on a `div`  works for you...

Comment: Which moving button are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

this can be fixed by setting float left to button

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

let playerTurn = 'X';

function runGame() {
 //for(i=0; i<9; i++) {
  buttons[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
   buttons[0].innerHTML = playerTurn;
  })
 }
```

```css
body {
 background-color: coral;
}

h1 {
 font-family: 'Lobster';
 font-size: 1.9rem;
 text-align: center;
}

button {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: relative;
 left: 35px;
 top: 35px;
 background-color: coral;
 border: none;
 margin: 4px;
 transition-duration: 500ms;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}
.row-1:after,.row-2:after,.row-3:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

button:hover {
 background-color: black;
}

.game-box {
 background-color: black;
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 border-radius: 10%;
 margin: auto;

}

.shave-left-top {
 border-top-left-radius: 10%;
}

.shave-right-top {
 border-top-right-radius: 10%;
}

.shave-left-bottom {
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10%;
}

.shave-right-bottom {
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>javaScript Tic Tac Toe</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>javascript Tic Tac Toe</h1>

 <div class="game-box">
  <div class="row-1">
   <input type="button" name=""> class="shave-left-top" onclick="runGame();"></button> 
   <button onclick="runGame();"></button> 
   <button class="shave-right-top" onclick="runGame();"></button> 
  </div>

  <div class="row-2">
   <button onclick="runGame();"></button> 
   <button onclick="runGame();"></button> 
   <button onclick="runGame();"></button> 
  </div>

  <div class="row-3">
   <button class="shave-left-bottom" onclick="runGame();"></button> 
   <button onclick="runGame();"></button> 
   <button class="shave-right-bottom" onclick="runGame();"></button> 
  </div>

 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS float:left added.

I changed JavaScript a little bit. After click every button, buttons will lose their click listener to not being clicked twice and playerTurn will swap.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

let playerTurn = 'X';

for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', runGame, false)
}

function runGame(event){
 playerTurn = playerTurn == 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';
  event.target.innerHTML = playerTurn;
  event.target.removeEventListener('click', runGame);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: coral;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Lobster';
  font-size: 1.9rem;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: coral;
  border: none;
  margin: 4px;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #ff6d6d;
}

.game-box {
  background-color: black;
  width: 325px;
  height: 325px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 35px;
}

.shave-left-top {
  border-top-left-radius: 10%;
}

.shave-right-top {
  border-top-right-radius: 10%;
}

.shave-left-bottom {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10%;
}

.shave-right-bottom {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
    <title>javaScript Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <h1>javascript Tic Tac Toe</h1>

    <div class="game-box">
      <div class="row-1">
        <button class="shave-left-top"></button>
        <button></button>
        <button class="shave-right-top"></button>
      </div>

      <div class="row-2">
        <button></button>
        <button></button>
        <button></button>
      </div>

      <div class="row-3">
        <button class="shave-left-bottom"></button>
        <button></button>
        <button class="shave-right-bottom"></button>
      </div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```